# java 10 execution environment using eclipse photon and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project using java 10 and I want to edit it in eclipse photon. It more or less works ok, but I do get the warning:

```
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

Setting the `java compiler` --> `JDK compliance level` to `10` in the project properties in eclipse doesn't remove this warning.

Is this an issue with the maven-compiler-plugin? I am currently using version 3.7.0 configured like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>10</source>
        <target>10</target>
        <release>10</release>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Tips on how to configure a maven project using java 10 and eclipse photon would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does right-click _Maven > Update Project..._ fix your issue?

Comment: @howlger right-click _Maven > Update Project_ did not fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my problem was related to the version of Spring Tool Suite I was using. It turns out that I had upgraded my environment using the update site instead of downloading the new version. I was using Spring Tool Suite 4.7.3a instead of 4.8.0. Using 4.8.0 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with the JRE specified on the build path of your project. Right-click on the project and then go to Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries. There, edit the JRE System Library specified to JRE 10.

Comment: if it is facet related problem, eclipse mentions it explicitly just the way it is mentioning about build path. Following Sanjeev's direction should solve your problem.